# Show that a frame field is (not) holonomic - only possible by going to the coframe?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields

$\DeclareMathOperator{\dx}{dx}\DeclareMathOperator{\dy}{dy}\DeclareMathOperator{\dnu}{d\nu}$
Consider in $\mathbb R^2$ the frame field $\{X=\partial_x+y\partial_y,Y=\partial_y\}.$
I computed its corresponding coframe field as $\{\omega=\dx, \theta=-y\dx+\dy\}$.

I want to show that the frame field is not holonomic.

I'm following two books.

1. One defines a **frame** field holonomic if it comes from a local coordinate system - $\{\partial_u,\partial_v\}$.
2. The other defines a **coframe** field $\dnu^\alpha$ as holonomic if $\dnu^\alpha=0$, and it then declares (locally) its dual frame field as holonomic.

The second definition is very practical, because for my example, differentiating the coframe shows $d\theta=\dx\wedge\dy\neq 0,$ so neither it nor the frame field are holonomic.

Is it possible (how?) to use the **first** definition for this example? That is, **can I show that $\{X,Y\}$ cannot be expressed as $\{\partial_u,\partial_v\}$** for some local coordinates $u,v:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ directly, without going to the differentials? $ А jesuitical answer is yes:

1. If $\{X,Y\}=\{\partial_u,\partial_v\}$, then the corresponding coframe field equals $\{du,dv\}$
2. Since $d\theta\neq 0$, it's impossible that $\theta=dv$ is an exact form.
3. Therefore, $\{X,Y\}$ is not expressible as $\{\partial_u,\partial_v\}$.

But this defeats the purpose of my question, because it simply translates the question in terms of differential forms, and doesn't show me what makes it impossible to find coordinates matching $\{X,Y\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ are coordinate vector fields if and only if their Lie bracket $[X,Y]=0$. In your case, $[X,Y]=-\partial_y$.

Comment: Oh nice. So the two fields should be constant with respect to differentiating each other, this really makes sense. Does this hold for higher dimensional manifolds?

Comment: Yes, this holds in general. Look at the proofs of the Frobenius theorem for integrability of subbundles of the tangent bundle.